# MusixTex: notes not appearing on the first stave

Tags: musixtex, music

I'm just beginning to find my way around MusixTex, but I can't get the first notes to work. The first line is drawn fully below the stave, barlines and all, and it's all out of alignment. I've tried with just a few notes, so it's not that it can't fit on one line. If it matters, I'm using the pdfLaTeX renderer in the TeXworks IDE.

Here's my code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{musixtex-fonts}

\title{kanoodling}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{music}
% setup
\normalmusicsize
\instrumentnumber{1}
\setname1{viol}
\setstaffs1{1}
\setclef1{6}
\generalsignature3
\generalmeter{\allabreve}
\systemnumbers %

\startrule %
\startpiece %

% system 1
\NOtes\ql{MN}\en\bar % anacrosis (bar 1)
\Notes\Qqbl JNON\Qqbl JNON\en\bar % b2
\Notes\Qqbl KNNM\Qqbl KMKJ\en\bar % b3
% system 2
\Notes\Qqbl IKNK\Qqbl IKNM\en\bar % b4
\NOtes\qa{^LJMN}\en\bar % b5
\endpiece %
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

and here's the output I'm getting:

[image: output pdf]

There's a possibility it has to do with how I'm rendering/exporting my file. The [MusixTex docs](https://texdoc.org/serve/musixdoc.pdf/0) say stuff about rendering it twice and I haven't figured out how to do that (because I'm doing it through TeXworks I think? The docs are telling me to use the command `musixflx` but I don't seem to have that installed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MusiXTeX spaces and empty lines produce at least ugly, often wrong output. Just inserting % at the end of every line and in empty lines, looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}%
%
\usepackage{musixtex}%
\usepackage{musixtex-fonts}%
%
\title{kanoodling}%
\begin{document}%
\maketitle%
\begin{music}%
% setup
\normalmusicsize%
\instrumentnumber{1}%
\setname1{viol}%
\setstaffs1{1}%
\setclef1{6}%
\generalsignature{3}% curled brackets added
\generalmeter{\allabreve}%
\systemnumbers%
%
\startrule%
\startpiece%
%
% system 1
\NOtes\ql{MN}\en\bar% anacrosis (bar 1)
\Notes\Qqbl JNON\Qqbl JNON\en\bar% b2
\Notes\Qqbl KNNM\Qqbl KMKJ\en\bar% b3
% system 2 be aware: if you do not insert \alaligne, MusiXTeX decides by itself where it breaks the lines
\Notes\Qqbl IKNK\Qqbl IKNM\en\bar% b4
\NOtes\qa{^LJMN}\en% b5 bar deleted, because \endpiece produces single bar
\endpiece%
\end{music}%
%
\end{document}%
```

In your case the empty line after `\startpiece` made MusiXTeX jump immediately to a second line (but without the system).

you indeed need to `musixflx`. I work with TeXShop editor, but `musixflx` in the Terminal. It should be installed in every MusiXTeX distribution, but is not a standard command in the editor.
In the Terminal (or the respective Windows environment) you must say:  musixflx /Users/name of User/directories up to the one where your file is stored/filname (without extension)

Then you have to set the file again.

Comment: yay!! it worked, thank you very much. turns out i had to re-download musixflx because it hadn't properly installed. as well as the lines thing.